# Can you add a longer word in Instagram poll word?

Tags: instagram

The word which is creating problem is HIGHTLIGHTS.

I'm creating a poll. Left word is small but right one is big. So it gives a line break. The strange thing is, you can add many words though and font size becomes smaller.

[image]
[image]

Is it a bug? Can it somehow be added?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late, but I just figured out how to fix this. You can add spaces between the two words and it should shrink the words because you're increasing the character count! Very weird bug I think.